# Trigger refresh for new media manager in 3.5

Tags: uploads, javascript, media-library, media-modal

I'm trying to figure out how it's possible to 'refresh' the media library in the new media dialogue in 3.5. I'm adding images from an external image library to the WordPress library (via a tab/iFrame combo in the media dialogue) which works ok, but I have to close and reopen the dialogue in order to show the newly added images (which *have* successfully been aded to the library).

I know there are `wp.media.editor.open()` and `wp.media.editor.close()` methods, but I can't quite manage to find a `sort()` or `refresh()` (or whatever) in the source. Truth be told, the source code is pretty intense reading and `console.log` doesn't seemingly help much with backbone.js. Any ideas?

Comment: One more Question to the gallery ***"New Media Manager: The Great Unknown"***. By the rhythm it goes, I expect full documentation and hooks around WP 3.7... All the upvotes indicate a hungry community.

Comment: Instead of refresh() function , we can use combination of wp.media.editor.close() and wp.media.editor.open() function to achieve the desired output.

Comment: In the featured-image-picker for example, there is a switch in wp-includes/js/media-views.js line 3644 for whether or not media library has loaded. It would seem to be referencing `wp.media.featuredImage.frame().views.get('.media-frame-content')[0].views.get("")[3].collection.length` but setting that length to 0 doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way of refreshing the content of the frame, as found in the WP core, is as below:

```
if(wp.media.frame.content.get()!==null){
   wp.media.frame.content.get().collection.props.set({ignore: (+ new Date())});
   wp.media.frame.content.get().options.selection.reset();
}else{
   wp.media.frame.library.props.set({ignore: (+ new Date())});
}
```

You should always check of the content is available, else refresh the library.

Cheers!

Comment: Where is this in WP core?

Comment: Are you sure this is still correct? It seems `wp.media.featuredImage.frame().options.selection.reset` exists but there is no `wp.media.featuredImage.frame().collection` for example.

Answer (score 4):

Took me a couple days but I finally dug my way through things enough to figure this out:

```
wp.media.editor.get(wpActiveEditor).views._views[".media-frame-content"][0].views._views[""][1].collection.props.set({ignore:(+(new Date()))})
```

Seems like there must be an easier way but that works for me in the meantime!

Comment: seems so intuitive :) nevertheless, this works!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: just found a "more official" way to do it: `wp.media.frame.content.get('gallery').collection.props.set({ignore: (+ new Date())});`, in this case i'm refreshing the `gallery` tab.

Comment: While both commands do trigger a refresh, afterwards you can no longer add images in the modal :( need another solution to this

Comment: This is still a far from ideal solution, but it's worth noting the `media-frame-content` key has changed from 1 to 2: `wp.media.editor.get(wpActiveEditor).views._views[".media-frame-content"][0].views._views[""][2].collection.props.set({ignore:(+(new Date()))})`

Comment: For the above reason you're better off using the more generic version posted elsewhere in this question: `wp.media.frame.content.get().collection.props.set({ignore: (+ new Date())});`

Comment: I'm finding that `wp.media.editor.get(wpActiveEditor).views._views[".media-frame-content"][0].views._views[""][2].collection.props.set({ignore:(+(new Date()))});` refreshes the 'Add Media' tab and `wp.media.frame.content.get().collection.props.set({ignore: (+ new Date())});` refreshes the 'Featured Image' tab.

Answer (score 2):

2019 update. I found a better solution that doesnt break the uploader:

```
wp.media.frame.on('open', function() {
    if (wp.media.frame.content.get() !== null) {          
        // this forces a refresh of the content
        wp.media.frame.content.get().collection._requery(true);

        // optional: reset selection
        wp.media.frame.content.get().options.selection.reset();
    }
}, this);
```

Answer (score -1):

is it what you are looking for

```
wp.media.editor.remove('content');
wp.media.editor.add('content');
```

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.