# Refreshing collections in the admin media manager

Tags: admin, uploads, javascript, media-library, backbone

I know this question is very similar to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/78230/31766) previously asked question; however, I was wondering if there was a more up-to-date/official way to refresh content programmatically in the WordPress admin media manager.

In my specific instance, I'm trying to integrate the Getty Images [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/getty-images/) with a select attachment modal (e.g., Featured Image).

Currently, I've been able to successfully extend a few methods of `media.view.MediaFrame.Select` to integrate the plugin and select the attachments:

```
var media = wp.media;

var parentCoreSelect = media.view.MediaFrame.Select;

media.view.MediaFrame.Select = media.view.MediaFrame.Select.extend({

  // REFRESH CONTENT
  browseContent: function(){
    var state   = this.state()
      , library = state.get('library');

    /**** relevant part, adapted from other question ****/
    library.props.set({ '__ignore_force_update': (+ new Date()) });
    /**** relevant part, adapted from other question ****/

    parentCoreSelect.prototype.browseContent.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  // add getty plugin functionality to select attachment modal
  createStates: function(){
    parentCoreSelect.prototype.createStates.apply(this, arguments);
    this.states.add([
      // new getty controller -- omitted for brevity
    ]);
  }

});
```

This works to refresh the attachment content and I can see freshly downloaded images from Getty once I toggle back to **Select an Image > Media Gallery**. At this point, however, when I upload files via the **Upload Files** tab in the same modal, the upload occurs successfully but the attachment content in the **Media Gallery** is not updated (i.e., new upload is not visible to end user, although meta data is displayed in the right panel).

Is there a better way to do this so I can maintain the normal upload functionality, where the fresh upload is shown and selected?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello! I am the original author of this plugin, and I would also like to work on figuring out why this piece doesn't work. It's also related to another plugin I'm working on. Wouldn't some official documentation be nice??