# How to trigger a refresh in the media modal

Tags: attachments, media, media-modal

I'm developing a plugin that adds a new tab to the media modal, and I need to know a way trigger a refresh of the attachments tab so it shows newly added attachments. This is the code I'm using:

```
wp.media.view.Toolbar.Custom = wp.media.view.Toolbar.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.defaults( this.options, {
            event: 'custom_event',
            close: false,
            items: {
                custom_event: {
                    text: wp.media.view.l10n.customButton,
                    style: 'primary',
                    priority: 80,
                    requires: false,
                    click: this.addAttachment
                }
            }
        });

        wp.media.view.Toolbar.prototype.initialize.apply( this, arguments );
    },

    // triggered when the button is clicked
    addAttachment: function(){
        this.controller.state().addAttachment();
        this.controller.setState( 'insert' );
        // I NEED TO TRIGGER A REFRESH OF THE ATTACHMENTS TAB HERE
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. The media modal documentation is almost non-existant.

Thanks

Comment: IIRC those are just Backbone/Underscore views. In other words, when you update the model, it should update the view by itself as the "ModelView" should trigger that.

Comment: Well, the `this.controller.state().addAttachment()` function is just an AJAX call using `wp.media.post()`, so I'd need to trigger an hypothetical "model updated" event somewhere after this AJAX call. Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" - currently, no. This is something where I'd have to invest quite some time to read through core (which I don't have now). About your comment: There's MarkDown available (See "help" below "add comment" button).

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78230/trigger-refresh-for-new-media-manager-in-3-5

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media

```
jQuery(function($){

  // Set all variables to be used in scope
  var frame,
      metaBox = $('#meta-box-id.postbox'), // Your meta box id here
      addImgLink = metaBox.find('.upload-custom-img'),
      delImgLink = metaBox.find( '.delete-custom-img'),
      imgContainer = metaBox.find( '.custom-img-container'),
      imgIdInput = metaBox.find( '.custom-img-id' );

  // ADD IMAGE LINK



addImgLink.on( 'click', function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();

    // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
    if ( frame ) {
      frame.open();
      return;
    }

    // Create a new media frame
    frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Select or Upload Media Of Your Chosen Persuasion',
      button: {
        text: 'Use this media'
      },
      multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    });


    // When an image is selected in the media frame...
    frame.on( 'select', function() {

      // Get media attachment details from the frame state
      var attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

      // Send the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
      imgContainer.append( '<img src="'+attachment.url+'" alt="" style="max-width:100%;"/>' );

      // Send the attachment id to our hidden input
      imgIdInput.val( attachment.id );

      // Hide the add image link
      addImgLink.addClass( 'hidden' );

      // Unhide the remove image link
      delImgLink.removeClass( 'hidden' );
    });

    // Finally, open the modal on click
    frame.open();
  });


  // DELETE IMAGE LINK
  delImgLink.on( 'click', function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();

    // Clear out the preview image
    imgContainer.html( '' );

    // Un-hide the add image link
    addImgLink.removeClass( 'hidden' );

    // Hide the delete image link
    delImgLink.addClass( 'hidden' );

    // Delete the image id from the hidden input
    imgIdInput.val( '' );

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out:

```
wp.media.editor.get(wpActiveEditor).views._views[".media-frame-content"][0].views._views[""][1].collection.props.set({ignore:(+(new Date()))})
```

Seems like there must be an easier way but that works for me in the meantime!

A more better way to do it:

```
wp.media.frame.content.get('gallery').collection.props.set({‌​ignore: (+ new Date())});,
```

in this case i'm refreshing the gallery tab.

Try both of the above codes and see which one works best for you.

Comment: This was helpful for me! Thanks.

Comment: yes  this worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

This works in the latest version of WordPress which is now 6.5:

```
wp.media.frame.content.get().collection._requery(true);
wp.media.frame.content.get().options.selection.reset();
```