# Media Modal not updating with file upload

Tags: media-modal

I'm looking for a solution with the media modal.  Here is the code that I'm using to create one that allows me to select files:

```
this._frame = wp.media( {
                    className: 'media-frame rwmb-media-frame',
                    multiple : true,
                    title    : 'Select Media',
                    library  : {
                        type   : this.props.mimeType,
                        exclude: ids
                    }, 
                } );
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I activate the modal and I go to the `Upload Files` tab and upload a file or two, the `Media Library` tab does not get updated.  It doesn't show the newly uploaded file.  The modal that gets called to insert media in the editor does update itself.  Is there an event I can leverage so I can do this?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78230/trigger-refresh-for-new-media-manager-in-3-5

Comment: This is seems to be a bug or at least an unfortunate side-effect of intended behaviour. See the issue on trac: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34465